# Is there any OSS that act as a Redis master, and proxy replication requests to a true Redis?

Tags: redis, replication

I'm trying to find a proxy that sits in between Redis master and slave, and talk to both Redis with native replication protocol. That is, it act as a master AND a slave:

```
Redis <--(slaveof)-- proxy  <--(slaveof)-- Redis
```

I've tried Googled it, and nothing came out.

Comment: You can setup a Redis server between the master and the replica to be a kind of proxy, but somehow I don't think that's what you mean. Why do you need a proxy?

Comment: @ItamarHaber Thx. Actually what I'm trying to do is to make two remote (deployed across far distant datacenters) Redis synchronize data, without any FULLSYNC risks. So I need a proxy sits in the middle to replicate data to remote Redis, that does not care how much lag the remote Redis fall behind.

Comment: Yep - I saw your answer to the same question in the mailing list. I'm not aware of an open source proxy that does that.